# Use of if-else in JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am learning ES6 and following is my ES5 code which is running fine -

```
var myArr = [34,45,67,34,2,67,1,5,90];
var evenArr = [];
var oddArr = [];

myArr.map(function(x){
  if(x%2==0) evenArr.push(x);
  else oddArr.push(x);
});
```

Now if I am converting this to ES6 I am getting errors of `Unexpected token` near `if`, let me know what I am doing wrong here -

My **ES6** code -

```
var myArr = [34,45,67,34,2,67,1,5,90];
var evenArr = [];
var oddArr = [];
myArr.map( x => if(x%2==0) evenArr.push(x) else oddArr.push(x) )
```

Comment: Arrow function bodies must be in `{}` if more than one statement. Seems you should be using *forEach* anyway, *map* creates a new array that you are throwing away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because the arrow functions accept **expressions** while you're passing a **statement**.

Your code is misleading: `Array.prototype.map` implies you would use the result somehow, while you are not.

If you wanted to improve the *semantics* of your code you would use `Array.prototype.forEach` that is designed specifically to iterate over an array and not return anything:

```
var myArr = [34,45,67,34,2,67,1,5,90];
var evenArr = [];
var oddArr = [];
myArr.forEach(x => {
    if (x % 2 === 0) {
        evenArr.push(x);
    } else {
        oddArr.push(x);
    }
});
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 9):

You should use ternary operator for inline conditions.

```
myArr.map( x => x%2==0 ? evenArr.push(x) : oddArr.push(x) )
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't use brackets to define the body of Arrow functions, the body should be an expression. In your case, it is not expression, but an `if` statement.

You need to define it with the compound body, like this

```
myArr.map(x => {
    if (x % 2 === 0)
        evenArr.push(x);
    else
        oddArr.push(x);
})
```

Or you should define it to return an expression, like this

```
myArr.map(x => x%2==0 ? evenArr.push(x) : oddArr.push(x))
```

**Note:** You should not use `map` to do this. `map` should be used only when you need to create a new array from the values of another array. You should use `forEach`, when you are dealing with functions which have side-effects. In your case, you are modifying objects which are outside the scope of your function. So `forEach` would be the best fit here.

Comment: Code golf: `myArr.forEach(x => (x%2? oddArr : evenArr).push(x))`. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If an arrow function body contains more than one statement, it must be contained in a block. Also, you can't omit semicolons like that.

*forEach* is more semantic (since your function just returns *undefined* and you don't keep the new array anyway) and you can use the value of `x%2` directly:

```
myArr.forEach( x => {if(x%2) oddArr.push(x); else evenArr.push(x)} )
```

and there's also:

```
myArr.forEach(x => [evenArr,oddArr][x%2].push(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myArr = [34,45,67,34,2,67,1,5,90];
var evenArr = [];
var oddArr = [];
myArr.map( x => (x%2==0)? evenArr.push(x) : oddArr.push(x) )
```

Try the code above. It seems to work.

I have just replaced `if..else` with ternary operator(`? :`).